# How to speed up the following Audit log query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

I am querying an `Audit` log table in an old commercial application. The `Audit` log has `13M` records. The table has `10` fields.  My query looks like this. I'm getting the users - from a date range that have Document ID in a customer table. Customer table has `800K` rows (The user who made a change in the documents table from `6/24/2021`-`7/4/2021`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Usrid, usrname as Usrname
FROM Audit
where tsstamp >= Convert(Date,'6/24/2021',101) and tsstamp <= Convert(Date,'7/4/2021',101)
and Docid in (Select docid from [Customer] group by docid )
group by usrid, usrname order by usrname
```

The `Audit` table has an index on usrid, usrname and tsstamp.  The Customer table has indexes on DocId.

What can I do to speed this up? New indexes? Change `SQL`? The current query takes approx `2` minutes to run. Running `SQL Server 2014`

Thanks in advance

[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1V8Kb-ad)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.557" Build="15.0.2148.135" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="18239.6" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" StatementSubTreeCost="164.664" StatementText="&#xD;&#xA;SELECT  Usrid, usrname as Usrname&#xD;&#xA;                 FROM ae_audit A&#xD;&#xA;               where tsstamp &gt;= Convert(Date,'6/24/2021',101) and tsstamp &lt;= Convert(Date,'7/4/2021',101)&#xD;&#xA;              and docid in (Select docid from [dbo].[Customer]  )&#xD;&#xA;               group by usrid, usrname order by usrname" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0xD2B5046EC138CF08" QueryPlanHash="0xAFE594D06EE293D1" RetrievedFromCache="false" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="80" CompileTime="30" CompileCPU="30" CompileMemory="1608">
            <ThreadStat Branches="3" />
            <Warnings>
              <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(date,[A].[tsstamp],0)" />
              <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Seek Plan" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(date,[A].[tsstamp],0)&gt;='2021-06-24'" />
              <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Seek Plan" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(date,[A].[tsstamp],0)&lt;='2021-07-04'" />
            </Warnings>
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="2048" SerialDesiredMemory="32464" GrantedMemory="0" MaxUsedMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="26424092" EstimatedPagesCached="3303011" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" MaxCompileMemory="2632800" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="28" EstimateCPU="0.151886" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="18239.6" LogicalOp="Gather Streams" NodeId="0" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="164.664">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
              </OutputList>
              <Parallelism>
                <OrderBy>
                  <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                  </OrderByColumn>
                </OrderBy>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="28" EstimateCPU="1.04933" EstimateIO="0.00563063" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="18239.6" LogicalOp="Distinct Sort" NodeId="1" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="164.512">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <MemoryFractions Input="0.134666" Output="1" />
                  <Sort Distinct="true">
                    <OrderBy>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                    </OrderBy>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="28" EstimateCPU="0.143659" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="30675" LogicalOp="Repartition Streams" NodeId="2" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="163.457">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <Parallelism PartitioningType="Hash">
                        <PartitionColumns>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                          <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                        </PartitionColumns>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="28" EstimateCPU="1.75944" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="30675" LogicalOp="Right Semi Join" NodeId="3" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="163.313">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="0.865334" />
                          <Hash>
                            <DefinedValues />
                            <HashKeysBuild>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                            </HashKeysBuild>
                            <HashKeysProbe>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="docid" />
                            </HashKeysProbe>
                            <ProbeResidual>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DEMODB].[dbo].[AUDIT].[docid] as [A].[docid]=[DEMODB].[dbo].[Customer].[docid]">
                                <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="docid" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Compare>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </ProbeResidual>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.282677" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="212146" LogicalOp="Bitmap Create" NodeId="4" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Bitmap" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="150.242">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <Bitmap>
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Bitmap1006" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <HashKeys>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                </HashKeys>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.282677" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="212146" LogicalOp="Repartition Streams" NodeId="5" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="150.242">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <Parallelism PartitioningType="Hash">
                                    <PartitionColumns>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                    </PartitionColumns>
                                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="49.4448" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="212146" LogicalOp="Partial Aggregate" NodeId="6" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="149.96">
                                      <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                      </OutputList>
                                      <MemoryFractions Input="0" Output="0" />
                                      <Hash>
                                        <DefinedValues />
                                        <HashKeysBuild>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                        </HashKeysBuild>
                                        <BuildResidual>
                                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DEMODB].[dbo].[Customer].[docid] = [DEMODB].[dbo].[Customer].[docid]">
                                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Compare>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </BuildResidual>
                                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="8.03384" EstimateIO="92.481" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="14606900" EstimatedRowsRead="14606900" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="7" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="100.515" TableCardinality="14606900">
                                          <OutputList>
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                          </OutputList>
                                          <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                            <DefinedValues>
                                              <DefinedValue>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" Column="docid" />
                                              </DefinedValue>
                                            </DefinedValues>
                                            <Object Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Customer]" IndexKind="Heap" Storage="RowStore" />
                                          </TableScan>
                                        </RelOp>
                                      </Hash>
                                    </RelOp>
                                  </Parallelism>
                                </RelOp>
                              </Bitmap>
                            </RelOp>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="32" EstimateCPU="0.183895" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="64596.7" LogicalOp="Repartition Streams" NodeId="8" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="11.3113">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="docid" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <Parallelism PartitioningType="Hash">
                                <PartitionColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="docid" />
                                </PartitionColumns>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="53" EstimateCPU="0.394836" EstimateIO="10.3809" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="64596.7" EstimatedRowsRead="717741" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="10" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="10.7757" TableCardinality="717741">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="docid" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                    <DefinedValues>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrid" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="docid" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="usrname" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                    </DefinedValues>
                                    <Object Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Index="[primeind]" Alias="[A]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                                    <Predicate>
                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(date,[DEMODB].[dbo].[AUDIT].[tsstamp] as [A].[tsstamp],0)&gt;='2021-06-24' AND CONVERT_IMPLICIT(date,[DEMODB].[dbo].[AUDIT].[tsstamp] as [A].[tsstamp],0)&lt;='2021-07-04' AND PROBE([Bitmap1006],[DEMODB].[dbo].[AUDIT].[docid] as [A].[docid],N'[IN ROW]')">
                                        <Logical Operation="AND">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Logical Operation="AND">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Compare CompareOp="GE">
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Convert DataType="date" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                          <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="tsstamp" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </Convert>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Const ConstValue="'2021-06-24'" />
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Compare>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Compare CompareOp="LE">
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Convert DataType="date" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                          <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="tsstamp" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </Convert>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Const ConstValue="'2021-07-04'" />
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Compare>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Logical>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Intrinsic FunctionName="PROBE">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Column="Bitmap1006" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DEMODB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[AUDIT]" Alias="[A]" Column="docid" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Const ConstValue="N'[IN ROW]'" />
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Intrinsic>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Logical>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Predicate>
                                  </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                              </Parallelism>
                            </RelOp>
                          </Hash>
                        </RelOp>
                      </Parallelism>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Sort>
                </RelOp>
              </Parallelism>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: No need for distinct if you have a GROUP BY

Comment: For performance questions please inspect and post your execution plan (check out Paste The Plan).

Comment: As well as the execution plan, we need to see table and index definitions. By the way, `DISTINCT` is the same as `GROUP BY` all columns, so one of them is superfluous. Also the `GROUP BY` inside the `IN` is completely pointless

Comment: I suspect an index that starts with tsstamp will be the first step in improving performance.

Comment: … select count(*) FROM Audit where tsstamp >= '20210624' and tsstamp <= '20210704' …what is the result?

Comment: Depending on the distribution of values a _single_ index on `Audit` with both `tsstamp` and `docid` in it ought to help. The best order depends on the distributions, so try both and see which the query optimizer uses. Adding `Usrid` (and _including_ `usrname`) _after_ those two columns will also help. Suggested reading: [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Comment: 64786  - select count(*) FROM Audit where tsstamp >= '20210624' and tsstamp <= '20210704'

Comment: … as commented above, an index on (tsstamp) and possibly include(docid) as a starting point might be worth testing ..[in combination with the exists() query in the answer below]

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: @lptr Be careful about using the word "include" when discussing an index. An index on `tsstamp desc, docid, Usrid` may improve performance. _Including_ `usrname` would allow the index so satisfy all the needs of the query, but it wouldn't be part of the key. [Create indexes with included columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) explains the difference. Enough people are surprised that an index can reference multiple columns, but to find that they can also carry other values along for the ride ... .

Comment: If you use "Paste The Plan" as suggested multiple times its much easier for us to see.

Comment: …it might be better to create an index on customer(docid) first..and an index on tsstamp won’t be that helpful since the column is not a date/time datatype

Comment: @lptr I was thinking along the lines of `create nonclustered index IX_OptimizeMyQuery on Audit ( tsstamp, docid, Usrid ) include ( usrname );`. I'm failing to grock in fullness the meaning of "..and an index on tsstamp won’t be that helpful since the column is not a date/time datatype", especially when the OP has, like most, failed to declassify the DDL so that we don't have to guess at data types. Or post the [graphical execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1V8Kb-ad) _for a different query_. Sigh.

Comment: ..@HABO .. in the plan: CONVERT_IMPLICIT(date,[DEMODB].[dbo].[AUDIT].[tsstamp] as [A].[tsstamp],0) and it appears as a warning too

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `EXISTS` here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Usrid
    ,usrname AS Usrname
FROM Audit a
   WHERE tsstamp >= Convert(DATE, '6/24/2021', 101)
   AND tsstamp <= Convert(DATE, '7/4/2021', 101)
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [Customer] c
        WHERE c.docid = a.Docid
       )
--Docid in (Select docid from [Customer] group by docid )
GROUP BY usrid
    ,usrname
ORDER BY usrname
```

Comment: Also highly unlikely to make a difference: `IN` and `EXISTS` are both transformed to semi-joins in most cases

Comment: My original query was  1:14 ,  this is  20 sec.  thx

Comment: you can add the screenshot of the execution plan to the question. I would suggest in such very big tables you should have a column which only stores the records date (without time stamp) and create an index on it.